# Apple Alu keyboard Hungarian layout 0 and í swapped

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, apple

I'm using a Hungarian Apple Alu keyboard. It works well, apart from that the `0` and the `í` keys are swapped. I [read here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Correcting_swapped_keys_and_wrong_keymaps_for_international_.28non-US.29_keyboards) that it could be re-mapped with an .Xmodmap file in the home folder.

What I don't know is how could I find out the appropriate keycodes to override? Is there maybe some "spy" tool that echoes keys pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

To get the keycodes to override the command is `xmodmap -pke`.

And in order to fix the swapped keys you have to insert these two lines in the `~/.Xmodmap` file:

```
keycode 49 = iacute Iacute backslash bar less greater
keycode 94 = 0 section doublelowquotemark rightdoublequotemark notsign notsign grave asciitilde
```

To apply the settings launch the command

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

And you're done.