# Lubuntu doesn't write "í" caracter

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I'm not able to write "**í**" character anymore.

I'm using **Lubunut** (Ubunut 14.04, LXDE). I have a **Dell SK-8115** keyboard whit Hungarian layout.

The "**í**" character is worked fine util that I configureted the **Keyboard Layout Handler**, because I need to use more keyboard layouts. (Currently I'm useing Hungarian, Italian, Greek and Armenian layouts.)

I tried to resolve whit the help of this topic:
[Apple Alu keyboard Hungarian layout 0 and í swapped](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219219/apple-alu-keyboard-hungarian-layout-0-and-%C3%AD-swapped), but I don't have the *~/.Xmodmap*, and I think this isn't the way to solve my problem.

After that I tried this: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Correcting_swapped_keys_and_wrong_keymaps_for_international_.28non-US.29_keyboards
But for `$ echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout`I recived the next message:

> tee: /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout: No such file or
>   directory 0

After that I tried to created **/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf** whit the text indicated in the link, but after `$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` I recived infinity time this message:

> libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse:
>   /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with
>   'echo'

What should I do? 
Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem is solved.
I don't know exactly what was the problem.

I tried to modify `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/hu` and I deleted *xkm* files from `/var/lib/xkb` (as is written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361128/why-did-13-10-break-my-custom-keyboard-layout/361584#361584).) I log out and log in, and found that the Hungarian layout is disappeard, so I restored `[...]/symbols/hu` and the í character function now, expect in Google Chrome, but this is an other question. :)

Comment: The problem in Chrome doesn't related with the problem mentioned in the question. I solved whit install the Chrome beta.
`sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable && sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta`

Comment: [Found here. (HU)](http://hup.hu/node/132960?comments_per_page=9999#comment-1741080)